# Enable/Disable button if the months are invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create navigation for months/year.

I wanted to Disable the `left` arrow navigation button if user is in `Jan` month and right navigation button if user is in `Dec` month.

Below is my code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.year = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.monthIndex = new Date().getMonth();
  }
```

**To navigate month**

- if "flag" is 0 which means that user click left arrow key <-
- if "flag" is 1 which means that user click right arrow key ->

Below is my code,

```
  navigationArrowMonth(flag) {
    this.monthNavigatorValidation(flag)
  }

  monthNavigatorValidation(flag?) {
    if(flag) {
      if(this.monthIndex < 0 || this.monthIndex >= 11) {
        this.isRightMonthDisabled = true;
        return false;
      } else {
        this.monthIndex = this.monthIndex + 1;
        this.isRightMonthDisabled = false;
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      if(this.monthIndex < 0 || this.monthIndex <= 11) { 
        this.isLeftMonthDisabled = true;
        return false;
      } else {
        this.monthIndex = this.monthIndex - 1;
        this.isLeftMonthDisabled = false;
        return true; 
      }

    }
  }
```

**HTML Template**

```
 <!--Month navigation-->

                <!-- 
                    On click should call navigationArrowMonth
                -->
                <button [disabled]="isLeftMonthDisabled" (click)="navigationArrowMonth(0)" mat-icon-button id="leftMonthKey" aria-label="left naviage">
                    <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left
                    </mat-icon>
                </button>

                <div id="monthValue" class="nameArrage" style="width: 120px;">
                    <!-- 
                        Display month in Alphabets
                    -->
                    {{months[monthIndex]}}
                </div>

                <!-- 
                    On click should call navigationArrowMonth
                    disable when limit reached
                -->
                <button [disabled]="isRightMonthDisabled" (click)="navigationArrowMonth(1)" mat-icon-button id="rightMonthKey" aria-label="right naviage">
                    <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right
                    </mat-icon>
                </button>

                <!--Month navigation end-->
```

But my code is not working as expected,

What i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Where are you using this code add template code to get better idea.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: `monthNavigatorValidation(flag)` is returning a boolean, try to not return a true or false value especially you are using  `isLeftMonthDisabled` and `isRightMonthDisabled` to disable the buttons

Answer (score 1):

This more simple solution

```
app.component.html
<h2>{{monthIndex}}</h2>

<div>
  <button 
    type="button" 
    [disabled]="monthIndex <= 0"
    (click)="onMove(-1)"
    >
    LEFT
  </button>
  <button 
    type="button" 
    [disabled]="monthIndex >= 11"
    (click)="onMove(1)"
    >
    RIGHT
  </button>
</div>

app.component.ts
year: number;
  monthIndex: number;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.year = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.monthIndex = new Date().getMonth();
  }

  onMove(move: number): void {
    this.monthIndex += move;
  }
```

Comment: This works fine, But I wanted `monthNavigatorValidation` to return true/false, to perform other operations  if the months are out of range

Comment: You can implement your logic into onMove method onMove(move: number): boolean {
    this.monthIndex += move; //your logic
  }

Comment: @hiremedroptaxiTaxi you should explore and use Angular's native support for forms validation. Writing everything programmatically (instead of leveraging the framework) soon leads to spaghetti code. 
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried removing the '?' after the function parameter here `monthNavigatorValidation(flag?)` ? To my eye that should be throwing a syntax error.</strike>

Comment: It's TypeScript notation for an optional parameter: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not validating both buttons on each move, and there is a bug with your conditions.

To fix your code, make a function responsible only for navigation.
As for validation make a separate function or directly use ***disabled** directive, simply like this:

for left month key

```html
[disabled]="monthIndex === 0"
```

for right month key

```html
[disabled]="monthIndex === 11"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many best approaches but since you are taking care of other stuff with this logic hence I fixed your solution, try it out.

```
  monthNavigatorValidation(flag) {
    if(flag) {
      this.isLeftMonthDisabled = false;
      this.monthIndex = this.monthIndex + 1; 
     if(this.monthIndex === 12) {
      this.isRightMonthDisabled = true;
      return false;
     } else {
      return true;
     }
   } else {
     this.isRightMonthDisabled = false;
     this.monthIndex = this.monthIndex - 1;

    if(this.monthIndex === 1) { 
     this.isLeftMonthDisabled = true;
     return false;
    } else {
     return true; 
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to write disabled like this,

```
 [attr.disabled]="monthIndex === 0 ? true : null"
```

In your Html tags.